# How can i make text change color when i hover the image

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying with css to make the text change color when i hover the image , but am not having any luck at all

```
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What is your CSS code that you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `li:hover` instead of `img:hover`.
In CSS it would be something like this:

```
li:hover a 
{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" class="img"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
</ul>
<style>
.img:hover~a{
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That's a good way to do this, using the sibling selectors of CSS3. But be careful, because I think it has compatibility problems in some browsers.

Comment: i checked it in firefox and chrome(windows and linux os)

Comment: Actually i don't really think that compatibility could be a problem on these days, just something to take in account for checking before implement that rule. For the record, here are a compatibility list on this selector: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector#compatibilitysection

Comment: Giving a link a class named 'img' does not make it an image - ie this does not answer the question.

Comment: i just give a class name you can change it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("img").hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().next("a").css("color","red"); 
});

$("img").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).parent().next("a").css("color",""); 
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YM5sv/10/)

Comment: I would avoid using JavaScript for something that can be done in CSS.

Comment: @MatthewDaly he tagge dthe question with jquery. Thats why i wrote it in jquery